# Xampp won't run mysql or apache

Tags: xampp

Every time I have tried to download xampp, apache and mysql won't work. I run them, but then a dozen errors appear saying that httpd.exe is running and preventing apache from running. The thing I don't understand is that httpd.exe is inside the xampp folder, so it's like it's blocking itself. I'm using windows 8, how to I instal xampp with no problems?

Answer (score 0):

Run XAMPP Control Panel -> Netstat, look for Port 80 (or 8081) and check the Process ID  (PID). Start Task Manager -> Services and look for the PID in this list. If you've found the process you just have to stop him (right click -> stop service or click on button "Services" at the bottom -> look for the Process Name -> right click -> stop).

Answer (score 0):

I know i may be late ..If there is any programs like skype.. i can help you when this prob again arises . With skype 1. take tools in skype and take connection options. 2. uncheck the "use port number 80" 3. also change use use port for incoming calls to any other.

FOR XAMPP 1. do one thing restart your system 2. take command prompt . 3. type netstat -ao 4. then you can get the PID for the port number 80.(remember this PID) 5 take task manager, click on services 6. find the PID which you have found in the command prompt ealier for port number 80 7. right click on it and stop the service.

Now you can take the xampp control panel and run apache and sql.. the issues will be solved.